# Enforce ANSI C Standard in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c, c89, visual-c++-2015

I am trying to get Visual Studio to enforce the ANSI C standard when compiling a project, but I can't get it to work.
Any tips?
I have read all the tutorials, I enabled the /Za option, and named my file as .c (not .cpp). However, the following program still builds successfully:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    }
    int f = 0;
}
```

But it shouldn't. It would have to be like this to respect the ANSI C standard:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(void)
{
    int i;
    int f = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    }
}
```

I would like the equivalent of the GCC options "**-ansi**" and "**-Wpedantic**".
Is this even possible in VS?

Comment: The first program fully (except for the `void main` bit) conforms to the current ANSI C standard which is the same as the current ISO c standard, commonly called C11. VS2015 doesn't support it. It only supports one *former* standard, C99, to which this program also conforms. If you want conformance to some other former standard like C89/90, you need to downgrade your toolset to something like v100 (VS2010), or use another compiler. There's nothing like `-std` flag in MSVC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/hh409293.aspx), MSVC 2015 seems to only support C99:

> **C99 Conformance** Visual Studio 2015 fully implements the C99 Standard Library, with the exception of any library features that depend on compiler features not yet supported by the Visual C++ compiler (for example, <tgmath.h> is not implemented).

There is no mention of C89 compatibility anywhere on that page.

The [`/Za` switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx) only disables *Microsoft specific* extensions:

> The Visual C++ compiler offers a number of features beyond those specified in either the ANSI C89, ISO C99, or ISO C++ standards. These features are known collectively as Microsoft extensions to C and C++. These extensions are available by default, and not available when the /Za option is specified. For more information about specific extensions, see Microsoft Extensions to C and C++.

It will not disable non-Microsoft specific extensions if they are part of an official C standard that it supports (like C99).

Comment: I guess what I want is the equivalent of the GCC options:
-ansi -Wpedantic

Can you confirm that this is not possible in Visual C++? 
Thanks

Comment: The first quotation refers only to the library, not the core language.